# Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the jQuery UI Dialog to provide a small pop-up that brings some information about a customer and shows a form. Everything works fine, except that it only works for the first click. If I try to click the same button again, or another one I get the error message:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'
```

I've managed to figure out it has to do with the closing/destroying of the dialog, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. If I comment the part `$(this).dialog('destroy');` then at least the dialog works but I get a different error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object Exclude something has no method 'dialog'
```

I've tried with jQuery 1.8.3/1.9.1 with jquery-ui-1.9.2 and I get the same problem.

This is what I have set up: http://jsfiddle.net/ycZpQ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** I found the real problem.

You were referring to all buttons on the page instead of explicitly deciding which ones.

```
$('button').click(function() {...});
```

Was attaching ALL buttons to the dialog showing - including the ones *inside* the dialog!

So I'll go step by step in the solution, while figuring this out I also found some other problems with your code that are mainly semantic or bad practice, I'll address them as well.

First of all, the buttons! By giving some differentiation to those buttons than others, in other words some common factor, you can make sure you don't address the wrong buttons.

```
<div class="buttons"> ... </div>
```

And then:

```
$('.buttons').on('click', 'button', function() {
    ...
});
```

Made sure I'm not addressing the buttons **inside** the dialog.

What this was causing is what I refer to as a dumbloop:

1. Click button -> create dialog
2. Click close button -> close dialog -> open dialog again (because this is also a button)

Now the problem that was causing the error, is the part where you give the dialog a title:

```
.dialog('option', 'title', $(this).attr('title'))
```

^ in here, because the button was the close button, you were trying to address **its** title and not the "Exclude" button for example, resulting in an error -- because that's a dummy button that was just discarded! It also doesn't have a title!

That's why the error was referring to object *Exclude something*, which is obviously not an object, but the title of the dialog. The close button received that object ID somehow between the close/open stage.

http://jsfiddle.net/ycZpQ/7/ <- here's a final JS fiddle, with only one dialog initialization and only opening the dialog when needed, which is the most efficient way of using this dialog system when the dialog is as reusable as it should be in this case.

Notes about more edits in the code: I made some changes to how the dialog creation looks, mostly semantic, but notice how I was defining the buttons - the `buttons` object is an object with buttons for properties, instead of an array of button objects with properties. A bit more efficient and a bit easier on the eyes.

Comment: Just one short question. So I shouldn't destroy the dialog? But then I still get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object Exclude something has no method 'dialog'`. This is what's confusing me.

Comment: Destroy the dialog only when you don't want to use it again. So, if you're planning on reusing it for different buttons, the answer would be no, don't destroy it. Closing it will hide it but keep it in the DOM, destroying it will remove the elements altogether

Comment: Removing the destroy causes no errors for me (except 404 on the AJAX page) http://jsfiddle.net/ycZpQ/3/

Comment: You're version is correct, if move the entire `$('#dialog-edit').dialog(...)` inside the `$('button').click(function(){...})` then it works. I don't get the `Object has no method 'dialog'` error. What's the explanation? I understand what I was doing wrong with the destroy during close, but what was after that?

Comment: No problem :) a rule of thumb is to always be specific yet flexible in your selectors. If you're going to have a lot of cases like these, you can remember that encasing them in a ".buttons" div will help you reuse code, but also don't be too general - you can't know when buttons will be generated or even added by you later on

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue when a single page used different versions of `jquery-ui.css`, `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery.js`.  To resolve this I just used the same version of the Jquery files

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about [.on jquery method](http://api.jquery.com/on/),

and then try something like this:

```
$('.dialog-edit').on("click", function(){
    $(this).dialog({ .... });
});
```

On close dialog try

```
$('.dialog-close').on("click", function(){
        $(this).dialog("close");
    });
```

P.S. Always use class not id. It's better way

Comment: #dialog-edit is the dialog itself, he wants to attach the dialog showing to a button - this code will never trigger

Comment: Chen is right, I already got that part working. The buttons work fine.

Comment: NEVER, and NEVER reference your objects with only a class-name. The script needs to traverse the whole DOM-tree to match all the matches, which is tremendously slow. ALWAYS reference the full path for your selectors. If you absolutely need to reference by class, at least provide a context (the 2nd parameter of $()), in where to find the classes.

Comment: Ok thanks! $('html body div div div button.dialog-close'). Eric this you meen?

Comment: Yes. I would tho recommend use some more info on the three "div div div" selectors. Like "div.wrapper div.container div.inner-content", or w/e you have set up. This is just to make sure it matches the correct tags, otherwise that selector is very general, and can cause problems if you got similar structures in any other place on your page.

Comment: Think It Depends from situation))

Answer (score 0):

Well, the destroy() method actually unbinds the container from the dialog-class. In other words, it removes the functionality.

If you want to close the dialog, you want to use the close() method. [Check it out in their doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close).

EDIT:
You shall only invoke the destroy() method when you don't ever need to use the dialog again.

Comment: The closing of the dialog works, it's what's happening during close that messes things up. I think you're right with the part that I shouldn't call destroy. But I get a different error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object <object name> has no method 'dialog'`

Comment: If you call destroy(), the object will no longer be hooked to the dialog-class in jQuery-UI. Therefore there exists no such function. You shall only invoke destroy() if you never going to use the dialog again. For example when you clean up some memory or so. Use the close() method instead.